# No route matches in rails when delete

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I am newbie to the rails and in my project I try to delete an user. But when I try it gives me error.

This is my index.html.erb  and path views>settings>srm>members>index.html.erb

```
 <%= form_tag({controller: "srm/members", action: "member_destroy"}, method: "delete", style: "display: inline-block;" ) do %>
    <input type="hidden" name="mid" value="<%= member["id"] %>">
    <button type="submit" class="edit-button" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this member?')"> 
      remove
    </button>
 <% end %>
```

This is my members_controller.rb and path of it app>controllers>settings>srm>members_controller.rb

```
  def member_destroy
   begin
   @url = api_version_root+'/users/'+params[:mid]
   response = RestClient.delete @url, api_token_hash

   flash[:info] = "User Deleted"
   redirect_to :back and return
   rescue RestClient::ExceptionWithResponse => err
   handle_rest_error http_code: err.http_code
 end
end
```

This is how I match the routes.rb

```
delete  '/settings/srm/members',     to:'members#member_destroy'
```

But It gives below error.

**No route matches {:action=>"member_destroy", :controller=>"settings/srm/members"}**

Am I doing wrong? Can anyone help me on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to know how you define the `MembersController` class and routes. I assume this is what you did:

```
class Settings::Srm::MembersController < ApplicationController
  def member_destroy
    # your code here
  end
end
```

Then, in your routes, you should do like this:

```
delete 'settings/srm/members', to:'settings/srm/members#member_destroy'

#  OR

namespace :settings do
  namespace :srm do
    delete 'members', to:'members#member_destroy'
  end
end
```

The key is in the path.